Set SSL on FTP Reverse Proxy
I have a FTP server (an old NAS) witch I cannot set a secure (SSL) channel
then I have another server (a backup server) witch store file only in a SFTP server.
So I have thought to create a reverse proxy in nginx to "convert" communication from backup server in SFTP an reverse it on NAS Server in FTP
I've created a new configuration server in stream part that listen on 22 port, added SSL certificate and reverse on internal unsecure ftp, but seams it doesn't work
here my configuration:
server {
    listen 22;

    #ssl on;
    #server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/selfsign_cert/self_cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/selfsign_cert/self_key.pem;

    proxy_pass 192.168.1.100:21;
}

I don't receive any error, but connection goes in timeout
if I enable ssl on; i receive unknown directive "ssl" on start up

Not fully sure what you are trying to do. But SFTP is not FTP over SSL - this would be FTPS and is found usually on port 21 (explicit SSL upgrade) or port 990 (implicit SSL). SFTP is instead file transfer over SSH, a completely different protocol usually on port 22.
And you cannot just "sslify" normal FTP through some SSL tunnel to make it FTPS, since FTP uses a data connection on port 21 and in addition to that a new TCP connection for each data transfer on some dynamic port. In addition to that it has new commands to control when exactly to use TLS - see RFC 4217 for the details.
Thus you would need to have a reverse proxy which actually implements the FTPS protocol and can translate between plain FTP and FTPS, a normal TCP/TLS reverse proxy does not work for this.
